# perl Get indexes of matches in array

Tags: perl

I want to search for an element in an array. What I want to get from this search is the all the indices of the array where I find a match.

So, for example the word I want to search is :

```
$myWord = cat

@allMyWords = my whole file with multiple occurrences of cat in random positions in file
```

So, if cat occurs at 3rd, 19th and 110th position, I want those indices as a result of it. I was wondering if there is a small and simple method to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I got the answer. This is the code that will return all the indices in the array where an element we are searching for is found.

```
my( @index )= grep { $allMyWords[$_] eq $word } 0..$#allMyWords;
print "Index : @index\n";
```

Comment: But that's a minor issue.  Overall this looks like the most elegant method.

Comment: For those like me looking for a string equivalent of this:
`my @locations = grep { substr($aString, $_, 1) eq "C" } 0..(length($aString));`

Answer (score 11):

With [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(indexes);

my @indexes = indexes { $_ eq 'cat' } @words;
```

If you haven't read the file yet, you can read it using "slurp mode":

```
local $/; # enable slurp mode
my @words = split(/\s+/, <>);
```