# Emulating PHP's array_keys function with idiomatic Perl

Tags: php, arrays, perl

In PHP, there is a function `array_keys` that when given an optional value will return all the indices of an array which matches the supplied value. So given this PHP code:

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));
```

It will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

Is there a more Perlish way of accomplishing the same functionality other than the below code? I seem to recall a `map` or `grep` trick for this.

```
my @a = ("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");

for ($i = 0; $i <= $#a; $i++) {
  push(@b, $i) if ( $a[$i] eq "blue");
}

print join(',', @b)
```

Comment: You got answers so that's good, but here is a duplicate, of [the question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4040050/4653379)

Answer (score 6):

The [indexes](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#indexes-BLOCK-LIST) function from the handy [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) package does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw/indexes/;

my @a = ("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
my @i = indexes { $_ eq "blue" } @a;
print Dumper(\@i);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't give all three matches because you need to use the less than or equal operator with $#a. $#a is the index of the last element so you need to include it. Or you could use $i < @a as in this example. In scalar context @a returns the number of elements which is one greater than the last index.

```
my @a = ("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
my @b;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++) {
  push(@b, $i) if ( $a[$i] eq "blue");
}

print join(',', @b)
```

The way to do this with grep is to pass in a range of numbers and use each one to index into your array and do the comparison. grep will then return the index to your matches array. Here is an example.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = ("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");

my @matches = grep { $arr[$_] eq "blue" } 0 .. $#arr;

print join(',', @matches)
```

[I found an old stackoverflow thread with a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222653/16210843)

Comment: And `for (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++)` is better written as `for my $i (0..$#a)`. (Of course, the `grep` is even better.)

Answer (score 2):

Sample code in case if you want to mimic behavior with subroutine

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = qw/blue red green blue blue/;
my $indexes = array_keys(\@array,'blue');;

say join(',',@$indexes);

sub array_keys {
    my $data = shift;
    my $item = shift;

    my($index, @indexes);
    $index = 0;

    for ( @$data ) {
        push @indexes, $index if $_ eq $item;
        $index++;
    }
    return \@indexes;
}
```

Output

```
0,3,4
```